# Helm Chart environment from values file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have the following values file:

```
MYVAR: 12123
MYVAR2: 214123
```

I want to iterate over them and use them as env variables in my deployment template:

```
env:
    {{- range .Values.examplemap }}
    - name: {{ .name }}
      value: {{ .value }}
    {{- end }}
```

I tried this

Answer (score 1):

For iterate over a map in helm you can try put this in the **values.yaml**

```
 extraEnvs:
   - name: ENV_NAME_1
     value: value123
   - name: ENV_NAME_2
     value: value123
```

So in your **template** you must iterate the extraEnvs like this:

```
 extraEnvs:
   {{- range .Values.image.extraEnvs }}
     - name: {{ .name | quote }}
       value: {{ .value | quote }}
   {{- end }}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the core [Go text/template language](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template), the `range` operator can iterate over either a list or a map.  There's specific syntax to assign the key-value pairs in a map to local variables:

```yaml
env:
{{- $k, $v := range .Values.examplemap }}
  - name: {{ $k }}
    value: {{ $v }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: This is about as useful as "go read the Go docs" if you don't put an example of what goes in `.Values.examplemap`